# Mindmap attributes (grow cycle, level 1 etc) in a Mymindmap/.style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, mindmaps

I well understood that `\tikzset` replaces `\tikzstyle`.

But I am missing something to translate the code from one to another.

Leading to the related question, how can I put the `grow cyclic,shape=circle,very thick,level distance=13mm,cap=round` that define the mindmap, in a `MyMindmap/.style` ?

Based on a simplified version on the cover page of [tikzpgfmanual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) for the stylized mindmap (You'll notice the `\tikzstyle` below)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling angle=120]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling angle=60]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling angle=30]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[fill]
\tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw]
\tikz [grow cyclic,shape=circle,very thick,level distance=13mm,cap=round]
\node {} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {red,green,blue}
{ node {} child [color=\A!50!\B] foreach \B in {red,green,blue}
{ node {} child [color=\A!50!\B!50!\C] foreach \C in {black,gray,white}
{ node {} }
}};

\end{document}
```

But I am struggling to swith it to `tikzset grammar`. MWE below does not work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
level 1/.style={sibling angle=120},
level 2/.style{sibling angle=60},
level 3/.style{sibling angle=30},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[grow cyclic,shape=circle,very thick,level distance=13mm,cap=round,level 1, level 2, level 3,every node/.style{fill},edge from parent/.style{draw},]
\node {} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {red,green,blue}
{ node {} child [color=\A!50!\B] foreach \B in {red,green,blue}
{ node {} child [color=\A!50!\B!50!\C] foreach \C in {black,gray,white}
{ node {} }
}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really just missing `=` signs (four of them). The correct syntax is

```
\tikzset{level 2/.style={sibling angle=60}}
```

and not

```
\tikzset{level 2/.style{sibling angle=60}}
```

so there are four `=` missing after `/.style`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
level 1/.style={sibling angle=120},
level 2/.style={sibling angle=60},
level 3/.style={sibling angle=30},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[grow cyclic,shape=circle,very thick,
level distance=13mm,cap=round,level 1, level 2, level 3,
every node/.style={fill},edge from parent/.style={draw},]
\node {} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {red,green,blue}
{ node {} child [color=\A!50!\B] foreach \B in {red,green,blue}
{ node {} child [color=\A!50!\B!50!\C] foreach \C in {black,gray,white}
{ node {} }
}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side remark, placing the `\tikzset`s outside the `tikzpicture` environment, which amounts to setting the pgf keys at the document level, defeats to some extent the purpose of using `\tikzset` in the sense that the settings apply then to all `tikzpicture` but for a `standalone` document containing just this picture this is not really an issue.

As for the comment, of course you can combine the styles to a new style.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{Mymindmap1/.style={grow cyclic,shape=circle,
very thick, level distance=13mm,cap=round,
every node/.style={fill},edge
from parent/.style={draw}, 
level 1/.style={sibling angle=120},
level 2/.style={sibling angle=60},
level 3/.style={sibling angle=30},
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[Mymindmap1]
\node {} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {red,green,blue}
{ node {} child [color=\A!50!\B] foreach \B in {red,green,blue}
{ node {} child [color=\A!50!\B!50!\C] foreach \C in {black,gray,white}
{ node {} }
}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, setting `level 1/.style` as in the first MWE and then just including just `level 1` will have the desired effect only "by accident", and probably bad side effects. That is, just including `level 1` in the list of styles of `Mymindmap1` will just evaluate the style. You have to tell Ti*k*Z explicitly that `level 1/.style={...}` since it will "try it out" with

```
 \tikzset{level/.try=\the\tikztreelevel,level \the\tikztreelevel/.try}%
```

The side effect (in this case) will be that if you have higher levels they will have the `sibling angle` of the last `level <n>` style that you placed.

Comment: cat. You're so fast ;)) I did not even have the time to edit my question wihich was would it be a good practice to have 
`Mymindmap1/.style={grow cyclic,shape=circle,very thick,
level distance=13mm,cap=round,level 1, level 2, level 3,
every node/.style={fill},edge from parent/.style={draw},},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[Mymindmap1]
\node {} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {red,green,blue}
{ node {} child [color=\A!50!\B] foreach \B in {red,green,blue}
{ node {} child [color=\A!50!\B!50!\C] foreach \C in {black,gray,white}
{ node {} }
}};
` to resuse the content or styles ?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb So sorry. ;-) Yes, what you suggest works with one small yet important modification. I tried to explain the subtle point.

Comment: i'll update the title of my question since it seems to be "Nesting styles with mindmaps" (?)

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb This nesting is not specific to `mindmaps`. These level thingies are already in `tikz.code.tex`. You can generally define a new style as a collection of previous styles.(There is now an "interesting" discussion on Meta. I think you should use the title that serves *you* best, i.e. what *you* think will help others to find the post most efficiently.)

Comment: which discussion on meta ? Ok i will reshape my question based on your answer.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb [This discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8561/194703).

Comment: Nice ! Merci :)